# Building an xml schema with unknown complex type

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have the following xml which I want to build a schema for:

```
<general>
  <files>
    <something>
      <sum>
        <count>100</count>
      </sum>
    </something>
    <something_else>
      <sum>
        <count>200</count>
      </sum>
    </something_else>
  </files>
</general>
```

The something/something_else tags could be named with any name.
I saw an option of using the xs:any but I haven't seen an example where it's used as part of a complextype.
I don't mind about the something tag name itself but I don't want to skip the validation of it's children (sum and count), as well as the general and files tags. 
Of course there might me n numbers of occurrences of "something" like tags with its sub trees.

Comment: Looks like it's an undefined data model, something and something_else should be attributes of a known object.

Comment: I dont think this can be done. If you have control of the XML, then change it to something similar: <general>
  <files>
    <item>
   <type>something</type>
      <sum>
        <count>100</count>
      </item>
    </something>
    <item>
   <type>something_else</type>
      <sum>
        <count>200</count>
      </sum>
    </item>
  </files>
</general> and the build schema.